# Default ModelBinding converts int field to 0 every time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, model-binding

I have a model that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Question : RatingItem, IQuestion, IXmlSerializable
{
// ...
    public int TextRows { get; set; }
```

And when I send it back to the controller via a post, Fiddler captured it like this:

```
...Question.TextRows=44...
```

But then on the very first line in my controller my break point says this value is 0.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RequiresResource(SecurityConstants.IndividualOverview_Configuration, eActions.AddNew | eActions.Update)]
    public ActionResult Save(int documentId, string evaluationVariableName, Question question)
    {
```

// question.TextRows is 0 here ...

Any guesses about what is going on?

I inherited this code, but I don't see any custom model binders that could be adjusting things.

What's even weirder is all the other properties percolate to the controller just fine.

Comment: Any reason for heaving an ASP.NET MVC view model implement `IXmlSerializable`? This looks like a complete mess to me. Can you show your full model code as well as the full Fiddler capture of the request?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Not a good reason. I think back in the day XmlSerialization required extraneous interfaces, and I'm afraid it will break something that won't show up in my unit tests. I'm afraid I'll get in trouble for disclosing our internal schema if I post this class' model (security reasons).

Comment: But if you don't show your class how do you expect us being able to help? I mean I can write you a simple ASP.NET MVC application with a view model having a `TextRows` integer property and a view containing an input field with `name="Question.TextRows"` and I totally guarantee you that it will work. So the conclusion is that the problem is in some part of your code that you haven't shown. For example some custom model binders or this crappy `IXmlSerializable` implementation that should never have been done in an ASP.NET MVC view model.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Yeah, I'd say that is fair. I thought I might have overlooked something (like TextRows being a key word or something). I will look into the suspicious interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason someone had written an automatic setter for a different field that was overwriting the field I was examining.

This would have been hard to determine from the information I posted above.

I thought I had set a break point in this setter that was not getting hit, but I can see it happening there now.

Thanks, Dan, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to say without seeing the view, but binding errors are almost universally related to bad field names in your form. For example, based on the code you've shown, you really shouldn't have a field named `Question.TextRows`, but rather just `TextRows`. The modelbinder will understand that it needs to put this in an instance of `Question` and pass it to your `question` param.

Comment: In this context having an input field with name `Question.TextRows=44` or `TextRows=44` is absolutely the same and totally doesn't explain why the model binding doesn't work.

Comment: That's probably true. Although it's important to note that that's because his parameter name is `question` and the modelbinder doesn't care about case, so `Question == question == QUESTION`. If the parameter name was changed to something else like `model` though, then it would no longer be true that it doesn't matter which the OP used. However, there's really nothing else to explain the issue here, and it certainly doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Try what? using `TextRows` instad of `Question.TextRows`? I agree that this might be worth trying but IMHO since his action parameter is named `question` the problem is somewhere else. Unfortunately we don't have enough context here to be able to judge.

Comment: Yes. That's what I was suggesting. And, like I said. You're probably right, but grasping at straws and all. Based on what the OP has presented so far, though, there's no other explanation.

Comment: Of course that there's another explanation. It lies in a part of the code he hasn't shown so far unfortunately such as his `IXmlSerializable` implementation. Unfortunately it appears that this is some sort of a top secret stuff that we are not authorized to see. So basically we can be speculating as much as we want without having any constructive conversation here.